# GoogleApiClient onConnected not called on Watch

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have read this thread but I still faced similar issue:

[GoogleApiClient onConnected never called on Wearable device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681722/googleapiclient-onconnected-never-called-on-wearable-device)

I tried to follow exactly how this works:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html

Here are my codes:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements DataApi.DataListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private static final String PATH = "/phonewatch";
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("phone watch", "On Create!");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Log.d("phone watch", "On Start!");

    super.onStart();
    client.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.d("phone watch", "On Stop!");

    if (client != null && client.isConnected()) {
        Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(client, this);
        client.disconnect();
    }

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("phone watch", "On connected! Add listener.");

    Wearable.DataApi.addListener(client, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d("phone watch", "connection suspended.");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d("phone watch", "connection failed.");
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged(final DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
    Log.d("phone watch", "Data changed!");
...
}
```

I only got this:

07-23 20:07:41.730  24874-24874/virtualgs.phonewatch D/phone watch﹕ On Create!
07-23 20:07:41.772  24874-24874/virtualgs.phonewatch D/phone watch﹕ On Start!

On connected and other log messages were not called. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks and GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, you have never registered your activity as a listener to receive those callbacks. When building the api client, you need to call the following two: addConnectionCallbacks(this) and addOnConnectionFailedListener(this):

```
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Wearable.API)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I made this mistake. Thanks for your help!